# Reading XML inner child node using c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to read xml in c#. I am able to read the node 'ArrayOfCruisePriceSummaryResponse' but how can i read the inner nodes.

```
XmlNodeList xmlnode;
xmlnode = xml.GetElementsByTagName("CruisePriceSummaryResponse");

for (int i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
{

}
```

Using `GetElementsByTagName` I am able to reach to that node but how can I read the inner child. I want to read `TotalPrice` from `BestFare` and `FullFare` Each child has two innerchilds `BestFare` and `FullFare`and I need to read each `TotalPrice` .

```
<ArrayOfCruisePriceSummaryResponse
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/OpenseasAPI.ServiceModel">
    <CruisePriceSummaryResponse>
        <AvailablePromos
            xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <d3p1:string>FLA</d3p1:string>
            <d3p1:string>FLB</d3p1:string>
        </AvailablePromos>
        <Brand>PA</Brand>
        <CruiseCategory i:nil="true"/>
        <RoomSize>
            <CruisePriceSummaryRoomSize>
                <BestFare>
                    <TotalPrice>2798.0000000</TotalPrice>
                </BestFare>
                <FullFare>
                    <TotalPrice>3198.000000</TotalPrice>
                </FullFare>
                <PaxCount>2</PaxCount>
            </CruisePriceSummaryRoomSize>
            <CruisePriceSummaryRoomSize>
                <BestFare>
                    <TotalPrice>2796.000000</TotalPrice>
                </BestFare>
                <FullFare>
                    <TotalPrice>4196.000000</TotalPrice>
                </FullFare>
                <PaxCount>4</PaxCount>
            </CruisePriceSummaryRoomSize>
        </RoomSize>
        <ShipCode>PD</ShipCode>
    </CruisePriceSummaryResponse>
    <CruisePriceSummaryResponse>
        <AvailablePromos
            xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <d3p1:string>FLA</d3p1:string>
            <d3p1:string>LF1</d3p1:string>
        </AvailablePromos>
        <Brand>PA</Brand>
        <RoomSize>
            <CruisePriceSummaryRoomSize>
                <BestFare>
                    <TotalPrice>1298.000000</TotalPrice>
                </BestFare>
                <FullFare>
                    <TotalPrice>3498.000000</TotalPrice>
                </FullFare>
                <PaxCount>2</PaxCount>
            </CruisePriceSummaryRoomSize>
            <CruisePriceSummaryRoomSize>
                <BestFare>
                    <TotalPrice>1796.000000</TotalPrice>
                </BestFare>
                <FullFare>
                    <TotalPrice>5396.000000</TotalPrice>
                </FullFare>
                <PaxCount>4</PaxCount>
            </CruisePriceSummaryRoomSize>
        </RoomSize>
        <ShipCode>PJ</ShipCode>
    </CruisePriceSummaryResponse>
</ArrayOfCruisePriceSummaryResponse>
```

P.S I dont not want to use LINQ because I am working on a SSIS project using VS2008 and it does not support LINQ.

Comment: Would you mind using the `XmlSerializer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the various `SelectNode` variants to traverse your document and extract your data.

Try this:

```
XmlNodeList xmlnodes;
xmlnodes = xml.GetElementsByTagName("CruisePriceSummaryResponse");

for (int i = 0; i < xmlnodes.Count; i++)
{
    XmlNodeList rooms = xmlnodes[i].SelectNodes("RoomSize/CruisePriceSummaryRoomSize");
    for(int j = 0; j < rooms.Count; j++)
    {
        string bestFare = rooms[j].SelectSingleNode("BestFare/TotalPrice").InnerText;
        string fullFare = rooms[j].SelectSingleNode("FullFare/TotalPrice").InnerText;

        // do whatever you need
    }
}
```

You might want to look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256039(v=vs.110).aspx) for information about XPath locations.

Comment: thanks @Amit. i am getting error 'System.Xml.XmlNodeList' does not contain a definition for 'SelectNodes'  i declared XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument(); and then XmlNodeList rooms = xml.SelectNodes("RoomSize/CruisePriceSummaryRoomSize");. but this is returning 0 value

Comment: @OwaisAhmed - You're right, I forgot the accessor (`[i]`). Your naming scheme confused me, so I renamed the variable and added the missing part.